# Solving for $t$ in a cubic function

Tags: cubics

I have a function 
$h(t)=5t^3 + 30t^2 + 45t + 4$

I would like to solve for t when $h(t)=50$

I have tried factorizing by inspection and by table but the function does not appear to have a real factorized form. How would I solve a function that does not have a factorized form?

Simplifying:

$50=5t^3 + 30t^2 + 45t + 4$

$46=5t(t^2+6t+9)$

Comment: It looks horrible: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5t%5E3+%2B+30+t%5E2+%2B+45+t+%2B+4+%3D+50 (one real root), try numerical methods like Newton's Method

Comment: You 'd probably be better off by using some numerical method.

Comment: Maybe ${46\over 5}=(t+3)^3-3(t+3)^2$ would be interesting?

Comment: Try rational root theorem or use the known method for solving cubic polynomial

Comment: you must use the Cardano formulas

Comment: $-2+\frac{1}{15}(18900-675\sqrt{759})^{\frac{1}{3}}+(\frac{1}{5}(28+\sqrt{759}))^{\frac{1}{3}} $ or approx 0.6795237112